# Django- Filter Models by date and user then total fields

Tags: django, date, django-models, filter, django-views

What I am trying to do is get models that were created, lets say 1/1/17-1/31/17, then total a FloatField of all the models returned. With that total, I want to populate a column on a bar graph labeled January. Then do the same for February... and so on.

Here is my model:

```
class Punch(models.Model):
    flag = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
    actual = models.FloatField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to filter by user and date range so in my views I have something like this:

```
        punch = Punch.objects.filter(date__range=[2017-01-01,2017-01-31])
        user = request.user
        punches = punch.filter(user=user)
        context = {'punches': punches}
```

So throughout the month the user is filling out a form entering an amount in the flag field then saving the Punch object. I want to get the total amount entered in the flag field for the month. This is were I get lost. I assume that I will need to have a for loop run through the objects but I am unsure how exactly to accomplish this. Also, should this occur in the template or in my views? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to iterate over your queryset to get the sum of `flag`, what you need to use is called aggregation, specifically we're looking at a `sum`.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet

so here's the code you need:

```
user = request.user
punches = Punch.objects.filter(date__range=["2017-01-01","2017-01-31"], user=user)
flag_sum = punches.aggregate(flag_sum=Sum('flag'))["flag_sum"]
```

What we're doing is asking for the `sum` of all `flag` values given our queryset `punches`, since we're calling the `aggregate` argument `flag_sum`, it will output `{"flag_sum":123.456}`, so we access it directly using `["flag_sum"]`, which will return the float value you're looking for.

Comment: also notice that you can give a filter multiple arguments, so there's no need to filter twice ;)

Comment: Thanks! Two great tips in one answer! I will read through the documentation you provided.

Comment: I am getting this error: "FloatField' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression'" on the flag_sum = punches.aggregate line. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Never mind, i went home and tried it on my VE and got a full traceback. I think i can tackle this error myself!

Comment: i think you might be able to ignore the `output_field=FloatField()` part of the code, i put it there because it's the example given in the docs

Comment: I fought it for a while trying to follow the example given in the docs. But you were right. Removing that bit of code solved the issue.

Comment: Ok, i'll edit the answer so it won't confuse anybody :)